# Atribuir subscribe para variavel global com angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Eu tenho método que faz um `subscribe` e me traz um array de objeto **enorme**.

```
getItems() {
         this.service.getItems()
         .subscribe(items => { this.listaItems = items;}, 
         () => console.log('msg de erro')
```

Preciso atribuir o retorno a uma variável global, chamada `listaItems` logo ao abrir a minha página.
então eu fiz:

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.getItems();
        console.log(this.listaItems) // undefined
}
```

Contudo, tem retornando `undefined` ao invés do meu resultado.

**Ele parece "pular" meu `this.getItems();` e executar meu `console.log(this.listaItems)` primeiro.**

service:

```
getItems =() => this.httpService.get(`apiURl`);
```

Comment: Sim, vai retornar **undefined**, pq está dando um log na variável, mas, a mesma ainda não foi preenchida com o valor retornado pelo service. Se envolver a variável em um **setTimeout** verá que a variável precisa de um tempo até ter o retorno!

Comment: Faz sentindo, já que meu retorno é grande. Nesse caso, como esperar que seja preenchido para depois fazer o log?

Comment: Cara vc não vai conseguir fazer nada com a variável antes que tenha um valor, e ela só recebe um valor no método **getItems()**, então terá que fazer o que precisa fazer lá.